# If $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ have probability distribution function $F(x)$, then the maximum has probability distribution function $F(x)^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A random sample $x_1,x_2,.....,x_n$ is taken from a population , which has the  probability distribution function $F(x)$ and the density function $f(x)$ .

The values in the sample are arranged in order and the maximum value of the sample is denoted by $x_{MAX}$ , We need to show that the distribution function of $X_{MAX}$ is $(F(x))^{n}$.

Can anyone provide me a hint for this , I know the definitions of density functions and distribution functions..
Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\max(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \le x$ is equivalent to $(x_1 \le x) \wedge (x_2 \le x) \wedge  \ldots \wedge (x_n \le x)$.